# C++ error when compile

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Hi I'm doing this project and when I compile it, I'm getting an error.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CService& obj) {

        os<<obj.GetClient()<<obj.GetSeller()<<obj.GetMusic();
        return os;

    }
```

and the error I get for this is :

```
error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters
error C2333: '<<' : error in function declaration; skipping function body
```

Comment: How about providing the definition of `CService`? Also, the second parameter should have type `CService const&`

Comment: What does get functions returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare this function *outside* the class body and inside the `CService` class declare it as a friend. Moreover, don't forget to make the class object `const`:

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, CService const &);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the reason for the error though. The compiler is not complaining about inaccessible members...

Comment: @AndyProwl It said the declaration had too many parameters so I thought he was defining inside the class instead of outside.

Comment: Oh, in that case it would make sense. I was assuming the definition was out-of-class